# I don't want to repeat the same code on javascript **new **

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new at this.... its to create a quote from three sections of the phrase: start. middle and end... and randomly select one from each.

The code works but I didn't want to repeat the code underneath with the Math.floor/Math.Random three times.

Any ideas on how to not repeat the code?

Thanks!

```
var quotes = {
  start: ["start1 ", "start2 ", "start3 "],
  middle: ["middle1 ", "middle2 ", "middle3 "],
  end: ["end1 ", "end2 ", "end3 "],
 };
 var quoteRandom = "";
 for (var y in quotes) {
 console.log(quotes[y]);
}

 quoteRandom += quotes.start[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]; 
 quoteRandom += " " + quotes.middle[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]; 
 quoteRandom += " " + quotes.end[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

 console.log(quoteRandom);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the power of a function and a callback, which is basically a function for another function which calls the function for each of item of an array, for example.

Methods used:

- [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) for getting all values of an object
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for returning a value for each item (in this case take the array and return a random item)
- and a function for getting a random value out of an array.

```js
function getRandomValue(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

var quotes = {
        start: ["start1 ", "start2 ", "start3 "],
        middle: ["middle1 ", "middle2 ", "middle3 "],
        end: ["end1 ", "end2 ", "end3 "],
   },
   quoteRandom = Object.values(quotes).map(getRandomValue).join(' ');

console.log(quoteRandom);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap  Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) as return value of function and reuse  same function where ever required to avoid duplicate lines of code

```js
var quotes = {
  start: ["start1 ", "start2 ", "start3 "],
  middle: ["middle1 ", "middle2 ", "middle3 "],
  end: ["end1 ", "end2 ", "end3 "],
 };
 var quoteRandom = "";
 for (var y in quotes) {
 console.log(quotes[y]);
}

function test(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
}

 quoteRandom += quotes.start[test()]; 
 quoteRandom += " " + quotes.middle[test()]; 
 quoteRandom += " " + quotes.end[test()];

 console.log(quoteRandom);
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zWGwPg?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

use `array.reduce()`. This way you don't have to worry about `start`, `middle` and `end` length

```js
var quotes = {
  start: ["start1 ", "start2 ", "start3 "],
  middle: ["middle1 ", "middle2 ", "middle3 "],
  end: ["end1 ", "end2 ", "end3 ","end4 ", "end5 ", "end6"],
 };

 
var quoteRandom = [quotes.start,quotes.middle,quotes.end].reduce((str,el)=> {return str+=el[Math.floor(Math.random() * el.length)]},"");
 console.log(quoteRandom);
```